# Merge two Dataframes based on a similar column from the First dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to merge two dataframes based on a similar column from df1

df1

```
            A      B
        0  john   id1
        1  parker id2
        2  david  id3
        3  will   id4
```

df2

```
            C          B
        0  letterj    id1
        1  letterp    id2
        2  letterd    id3
        3  letterw    id4
        4  lettert    id5
        5  lettero    id7
```

final_df

```
            A      B        C
        0  john   id1    letterj
        1  parker id2    letterp
        2  david  id3    letterd
        3  will   id4    letterw
```

Comment: How is letterj similar to john? It is because it starts with j?

Comment: yes to make it easy for viewing

Comment: So you want to merge on 'B'?

Answer (score 1):

```
you need,

df1.merge(df2,on='B')


   A      B        C
0  john   id1    letterj
1  parker id2    letterp
2  david  id3    letterd
3  will   id4    letterw
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge two dataframes based on a similar column from df1 you have to do this :

```
final_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, how ='left', on="B")
```